# "Invalid RGBA argument" error when specifying list of colours for errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I want to have different colour error bars for each point like this:

[image: example]

I am trying this code:

```
ax.errorbar([450.,500.], [4,5] , xerr = ([20.,15.],[20.,15.]), fmt ='o',color=['r','b'], ecolor = ['r','b'],ms=4, capsize=4,)
```

but I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
  238         # float)` and `np.array(...).astype(float)` all convert "0.5" to 0.5.
    239         # Test dimensionality to reject single floats.
--> 240         raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))
    241     # Return a tuple to prevent the cached value from being modified.
    242     c = tuple(c.astype(float))

ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: ['r', 'b']
```

Comment: What did you intend to achieve by setting the "color" attribute of an errorbar to `['r', 'b']`?

Comment: I'd like the error bar for each point to have a different colour. If I do color = 'blue' it works fine.

Comment: I've added an image of the sort of thing I'm aiming for

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you will have to add them to the plot one by one

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([450., 500., 550., 600.])
y = np.array([4, 5, 4.5, 6])
xerr = np.array([[20.,15.],[20.,15.], [10.,25.], [12.,18.]])
color = 'rbyg'
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.gca().errorbar(x[i], y[i], xerr=xerr[i].reshape(2, -1),
                        fmt ='o',
                        color=color[i%len(color)],
                        ecolor=color[i%len(color)],
                        ms=4,
                        capsize=4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The part ``i%len(color)`` will make it to repeat the colors cyclically if there are more points than colors.

Comment: great, it would be nice if you could set the question as answered :) thanks!